# Using LIKE for two tables at once

Tags: mysql

Let the two tables be named "blog" and "videos".
Inside these two tables, there is a "content" column.
I want it to search on both using LIKE. Should return all matching data

`SELECT * FROM blog JOIN videos ON blog.content = videos.content WHERE blog.content LIKE "%Data%"`
I tried a query like this. I tried many queries but I couldn't do what I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to search for rows in both the `blog` and `videos` tables where the `content` column contains the word `Data`, you can use the `UNION` operator to combine the results of two separate `SELECT` statements.

Here's an example query:

```
SELECT * FROM blog WHERE content LIKE "%Data%"
UNION
SELECT * FROM videos WHERE content LIKE "%Data%";
```

This query will return all matching rows from both tables where the "content" column contains the word "Data."

Comment: Not working. I am getting this error; "The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns"

Comment: you can explicitly select the columns you want from both tables and make sure the column names match.

Comment: Both tables have the same column. No name errors.

Comment: I mean you can rewrite the query like this.

`select blog.column1 from blog where blog.content like "%Data%"
union
select videos.column1 from videos where videos.content like "%Data%"`

here you explicitly say that you want only `column1` from each table.

Comment: Thanks this query worked. But since the tables are different, I had to separate the data from each other. It would be better if there was a single query that I could do without separating the data.